# How variable 'a' will exist without any object creation?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

How variable **int a** is in existence without object creation? It is not of static type also.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data
{
public:
    int a;
    void print() { cout << "a is " << a << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Data *cp;
    int Data::*ptr = &Data::a;
    cp->*ptr = 5;
    cp->print();
}
```

Comment: 2 words: _undefined behavior_.

Comment: I am not able to understand. will you please explain further..

Comment: What explanation do you need? Accessing memory you didn't allocate is _undefined behavior_. Anything may happen (including _appearing_ to work, crashing your application, or crashing your application at undetermined point in time), according to the standard.

Comment: More explicitly, `Data *cp;` creates a pointer that's able to point to a `Data` object, but it isn't initialised so could point anywhere.  Then you dereference it which has undefined behaviour.

Comment: ok thanks, I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows some **undefined behavior**, let's go through it:

### Data *cp;

Creates a pointer on the stack, though, does not initialize it. On it's own not a problem, though, it should be initialized at some point. Right now, it can contain `0x0badc0de` for all we know.

### int Data::*ptr=&Data::a;

Nothing wrong with this, it simply creates a pointer to a member.

### cp->*ptr=5;

Very dangerous code, you are now using `cp` without it being initialized. In the best case, this crashes your program. You are now assigning `5` to the memory pointed to by `cp`. As this was not initialized, you are writing somewhere in the memory space. This can include in the best case: memory you don't own, memory without write access. In both cases, your program can crash. In the worst case, this actually writes to memory that you do own, resulting in corruption of data.

### cp->print();

Less dangerous, still undefined, so will read the memory. If you reach this statement, the memory is most likely allocated to your program and this will print `5`.

### It becomes worse

This program might actually just work, you might be able to execute it because your compiler has optimized it. It noticed you did a write, followed by a read, after which the memory is ignored. So, it could actually optimize your program to: `cout << "a is "<< 5 <<endl;`, which is totally defined.

So if this actually, for some unknown reason, would work, you have a bug in your program which in time will corrupt or crash your program.

Please write the following instead:

```
int main()
{
    int stackStorage = 0;
    Data *cp = &stackStorage;
    int Data::*ptr=&Data::a;
    cp->*ptr=5;
    cp->print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a bit more on the types used in this example.

```
int Data::*ptr=&Data::a;
```

For me, ptr is a pointer to int member of Data. `Data::a` is not an instance, so the address operator returns the offset of `a` in `Data`, typically 0.

```
cp->*ptr=5;
```

This dereferences cp, a pointer to Data, and applies the offset stored in ptr, namely 0, i.e., a;

So the two lines

```
int Data::*ptr=&Data::a;
cp->*ptr=5;
```

are just an obfuscated way of writing

```
cp->a = 5;
```